# Which process is accessing network?

Tags: networking

On Windows, is there an easy way to determine which process is currently accessing the network? The wifi icon is always lit(telling me it is transferring sth.), I am curious what process is causing this.

Comment: shouldn't this question be asked on SuperUser !

Comment: @Echo Lu - I agree with Manaf, throw a block of code in your question so it doesn't get close. Knowing how to find this information is useful to windows programmers in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of ways how to do that.

One is you use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), another is [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) (quick link: http://live.sysinternals.com/Tcpview.exe).

WireShark gives you more info, but is not as easy to use as tcpview.

Answer (score 0):

A packet sniffer like wireshark is useful if you want to see exactly what is going on, but if you just want to see what process is using data then netlimiter (netlimiter.com) is very useful. The free monitor version should work fine.